# Why is char being converted into a ushort instead of an int in this decompilation?

Tags: c#

When i write a for loop as below it works fine.

```
for (Char ch = 'A'; ch < 'Z'; ch++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString());
}
```

I thought that compiler converts Char type to int but when i looked at the decompiled code, this is what i saw:

```
for (char i = 65; i < 97; i = (ushort)i + 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

Can someone please explain why the compiler did not change the datatype of i from non-numeric to numeric?

--EDIT-- Added decompiler screenshot
[image]

Comment: How about explaining why you thought it would.

Comment: because if you write char i = 65; i < 97; i = (ushort)i + 1 in IDE, it wont work.

Comment: Everything is just bits under the hood.  Who knows how many conversion happened between compile and decompile.

Comment: are you sure of the decompiled version you saw? For example, if it was `for (char i = (char)65; i < (char)97; i = (char)(ushort)(i + 1))`, that would compile.

Comment: Can you explain why you thought that the compiler converts chars to ints? That's not what it is documented as doing.

Comment: How about using a different decompiler? Most decompilers for .net are pretty new and unpolished, so many of them simply produce wrong decompiled code. It's just one but in the decompiler. Most of them have plenty.

Answer (score 11):

To answer the question title,

> Why is char being converted into a ushort instead of an int in this decompilation?

Chars are 16-bit, and so are unsigned shorts. There simply isn't a need to convert to any larger-ranged type. The decompiler you used was probably working based on that.

To answer your edited question,

> Can someone please explain why the compiler did not change the datatype of i from non-numeric to numeric?

It's precisely because chars, while they have corresponding numeric **character codes**, aren't themselves the same as numeric types. You can cast an integer to a char, but they're not the same thing. Consequently, `((char) 65).ToString()` is not the same as `((int) 65).ToString()`.

---

For the record, .NET Reflector 7 decompiles your code to this:

```
for (char ch = 'A'; ch < 'Z'; ch = (char) (ch + '\x0001'))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString());
}
```

No sign of any integers anywhere according to Reflector. The code is almost identical to what you originally wrote.

If you want to look at what's really happening, look at the IL.

Comment: Char is not a numeric type. How compiler assigns 65 to char datatype? If i try to say char c = 65;, it throws error bcz 65 cannot be assigned to Char.

Comment: What do you use to decompile? Reflector?

Comment: yeah. i dont care if it converts to Int or long or double. How compiler assigns numeric value to a non-numeric type is what my question is.

Comment: If you don't care, why ask "Can someone please explain why the compiler did not change the datatype of i from Char to Int?" So do I delete my answer now?

Comment: please do so if you feel like doing so.

Answer (score 0):

A char can be implicitly converted to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal

Comment: Yes, but how does it relate to the question?